# Error when overloading opertor>> for string memebrs in the class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, inputstream

When I input the value for the *string* types, for examples:

> `_ho` I typed `Peter`
>    `_hoten` I typed `Peter Parker`
>    `_ten`   I typed `Marry`

My output on the screen was:

> `Peter` `Peter` `Marry`

Here is my code:

```
class SinhVien
{
private:
    string _ho;
    string _tenlot;
    string _ten;
public:
    static int InstanceCount;
    SinhVien();
    string ToString() const;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, SinhVien* p);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const SinhVien* p);
    ~SinhVien();
};
istream& operator>>(istream& in, SinhVien *p)
{
    cout << "Nhap ho: \n";
    in >> p->_ho;
    rewind(stdin);
    cout << "Nhap ten lot: \n";
    in >>  p->_tenlot;
    rewind(stdin);
    cout << "Nhap ten: \n";
    in >> p->_ten;
    return in;
}
string SinhVien::ToString() const
{
    stringstream writer;
    writer << _ho << " " << _tenlot << " " << _ten << "\n";
    return writer.str();
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const SinhVien* p)
{
    out << p->ToString();
    return out;
}

void main()
{
    SinhVien *a;
    a = new SinhVien();
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    cout << "\nTo string:\n";
    cout << a->ToString();
    delete a;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the functions. Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: @P.W I have updated the post.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but, you can simplify the code as well as make it more performant (not important here but good practice is good practice) by eliminating pointers and `new`/`delete` by automatically allocating `SinhVien` i.e. `SinhVien* a = new SinhVien` -> `SinhVien a;` and passing by reference instead of by pointer, i.e. `istream& operator>>(istream& in, SinhVien *p)` -> `istream& operator>>(istream& in, SinhVien& p)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `std::basic_istream::operator>>` overload, you need to use [std::geline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `std::cin >>`, so that you can get complete *input name* with *spaces*.

Secondly, you should pass the reference of the object pointer, so that the change will be applied to the passed object, not to its copy.

Fix:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, SinhVien* &p)
{                                                // ^^ take ref of object you pass, so that the change will be applied to the object, not to the copy of it.
    std::cout << "Nhap ho: \n";
    std::getline(in, p->_ho);   // change
    std::rewind(stdin);
    std::cout << "Nhap ten lot: \n";
    std::getline(in, p->_tenlot);   // change
    std::rewind(stdin);
    std::cout << "Nhap ten: \n";
    std::getline(in, p->_ten);   // change
    return in;
}
```

Above will work for one single input. However, the case of multiple inputs and use of `std::cin >>` in the `main()` can cause again some input skipping problems. Thanks to @Yksisarvinen pointing this out.
You can read more in this SO post: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction())

---

**Side note**: In modern C++, you do not need to manage the raw pointers, anymore. Because you have *[smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers)* which will manage your object's lifetime as it goes out of scope. So use it whenever its possible.

That means you can do something like this: <kbd>[SEE LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jg0oPXPiGKlCTYNw)</kbd>

```
#include <memory>

class SinhVien
{
private: // memebrs
public:
    // other member functions
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, const std::unique_ptr<SinhVien> &p);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const std::unique_ptr<SinhVien> &p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, const std::unique_ptr<SinhVien> &p)
{                                                                          
    std::cout << "Nhap ho: \n";
    std::getline(in, p->_ho);   // change
    std::cout << "Nhap ten lot: \n";
    std::getline(in, p->_tenlot);   // change
    std::rewind(stdin);
    std::cout << "Nhap ten: \n";
    std::getline(in, p->_ten);   // change
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::unique_ptr<SinhVien> &p)
{
    return out << p->ToString();
}

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<SinhVien>();
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a;
    std::cout << "\nTo string:\n";
    std::cout << a->ToString();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JeJo one more thing. Why do we add the std:: before every our operator?

Comment: @F.Wu Because `using namespace std;` is [considered as a bad coding paractice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Read the link for more info.